Object turns inside out when applying transform
for a school project i have to model from reference and eventually put in into unreal engine.
When i thought i was finally done i hit apply transform, and some of my objects turned inside out? i checked if i have any flipped normals, and that doesnt seem to be the case. i would like to know why this is happening and how to prevent it.
thank you for your time.


hello, maybe your objects have modifiers and apply rotation has unexpected results? In that case, apply the modifiers?

Is this really "inside out" or is it "mirrored"? I guess you have negative scale + modifiers

It's because your object had negative scale. An object can look fine with unapplied negative scale but when you tell Blender "Ok applying transforms, this is what I want the default to be" it has to apply that -1 value to the the entire mesh, which multiplies your normal vectors by -1, flipping them.



Just select all in edit mode and press Shift+N to recalc the normals. If you want to avoid it then try not to do too much mesh scaling in Object mode, either scale in Edit mode or use a mirror modifier which handles this math under the hood.
